# bokeh line plot with string x value

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to make out a bokeh line plot with string x-value but I just get an empty bokeh plot

```
sample={'A':['2012-01','2012-02','2012-03'],'B':[7,8,9]}

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
source2 = ColumnDataSource(sample)
p = figure(width=400, height=400)
p.line(x='A',y='B',source=source2, line_width=2)
output_notebook()
show(p)
```

Comment: For future questions, please provide always [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and if you have an error message, please add this error message to your post. This error message can be python of javascript. Therefor please check your browser console, too.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice, you should always check the imports. In your example two imports are missing.

To use date representation in bokeh, you can set the `x_axis_type` to `"datetime"` but this will enable only the DatetimeFormatter. Befor this, you have to transform the date string somehow into a number. One easy option is to use `pandas.to_datetime()`.

This tutorial shows how to [enable datetime axes](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/first_steps/first_steps_4.html?highlight=datetime#enabling-datetime-axes).

### Example

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

sample={'A':[pd.to_datetime(x) for x in ['2012-01','2012-02','2012-03']],'B':[7,8,9]}
source = ColumnDataSource(sample)
p = figure(width=400, height=400,  x_axis_type='datetime')
p.line(x='A', y='B', source=source, line_width=2)
output_notebook()
show(p)
```

### Output

[image: line plot with datetime x-axis]